# latest Luna eclipse PDT does not give common function suggestions

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt, php-ide

I was using helios version of PDT but it was compatible only till `v5.3` so I downloaded latest luna version to get `v5.5` support from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/SR1/eclipse-php-luna-SR1-win32-x86_64.zip).
but after downloading this instead of supporting new functions it stopped showing hints for most of the new/old functions such as `crypt()`,`str_replace()` etc.

Actully none of the string,array,mysqli etc functions are suggested how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Due bug in DLTK you have to manualy remove H2 database from you workspace after upgrade.

Howto fix this:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Go to folder : $workspace_dir/.metadata/.plugins
3. Remove org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2 dir
4. Start Eclipse
5. Waiting for DLTK index